# MongoDB graphLookup using AggregateFluentExtensions

Tags: c#, mongodb, aggregation-framework

I've been trying to execute a MongoDB graphLookup using latest C# driver which uses **AggregateFluentExtensions**. According to the [documentation](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.7/apidocs/html/Overload_MongoDB_Driver_IAggregateFluentExtensions_GraphLookup.htm): 
the method receives a series of parameters that I can't find a way to make work.

**Has anybody used it and could help me with an example?**

This is the json version of my aggregation:

```js
db.getCollection("Item").aggregate(
    [
        { 
            "$project" : {
                "itemMasterId" : 1.0, 
                "parentItemId" : 1.0
            }
        }, 
        { 
            "$graphLookup" : {
                "from" : "Item", 
                "startWith" : "$itemMasterId", 
                "connectFromField" : "itemMasterId", 
                "connectToField" : "parentItemId", 
                "as" : "ancestors", 
                "maxDepth" : 10, 
                "depthField" : "depthField", 
                "restrictSearchWithMatch" : {
                    "locationId" : 26
                }
            }
        }, 
        { 
            "$project" : {
                "itemMasterId" : 1.0, 
                "parentItemId" : 1.0, 
                "children.itemMasterId" : 1, 
                "children.parentItemId" : 1
            }
        }
    ]
);
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

(Late in the party, I hope it helps someone.)

I have used AppendStage() method, you can try this:

```
var graphLookupStage = new BsonDocument("$graphLookup",
                        new BsonDocument
                            {
                                    { "from", "someCollection" },
                                    { "startWith", "$reportsTo" },
                                    { "connectFromField", "reportsTo"},
                                    { "connectToField",  "name" },
                                    { "as", "reportingHierarchy" },
                                    { "maxDepth", 1 },
                                    { "depthField", "depthField" } //optional
                        });
var result = collection.Aggregate().AppendStage<BsonDocument>(graphLookupStage);
```